# SystemJS Configuration For TypeScript Export Declaration Of External Javascript Library

Tags: typescript, angular, systemjs

I'm very new to Angular2 and Typescript.
I want to find a way to gracefully use external js library:
I know, i can use:

```
declare var somelibrary: any;
somelibrary.doAnithing();
```

But I want to have some typization, so i read [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules-working-with-other-javascript-libraries) for the use of *.d.ts

So i create a module `chart.d.ts` :

```
export declare class Chart {
    constructor (ctx: any);

    Doughnut(data: any, options: any): Function;
}
```

(I try also:)

```
export declare module 'chart' {
    export class Chart {
        constructor (ctx: any);

        Doughnut(data: any, options: any): Function;
    }
}
```

and reference it, trying many ways:

```
// version 1
import chartFactory = require('../chart');
// version2
import { Chart } from '../chart';
```

and use it:

```
// version 1 usage    
new  chartFactory.Chart(ctx).Doughnut(this.chart1, {responsive : true});
```

or for the second import:

```
// version 2 usage
new  Chart(ctx).Doughnut(this.chart1, {responsive : true});
```

**The compilation succeds**, but on runtime **SystemJS** try to load the js implementation of my definition searching `'path/to/chart.js'` (obviusly there isn't any chart.js, the original library is imported with script tag).

The configuration of SystemJS is the same as angular tutorial:

```
System.config({
    packages: {
        app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    }
});
```

the `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Some suggestions with explaination?

I think the cause of the failed loockup is `"module": "system"` but the question is: How to do internal d.ts without conflicting with SystemJS resolution?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for are **ambient modules** you can read more about it in the handbook [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules-working-with-other-javascript-libraries).

You can declare one like this ( in **chart.d.ts**):

```js
declare module "chart" {
    export class Chart {
        constructor (ctx: any);
        Doughnut(data: any, options: any): Function;
    }
}
```

And you should be able to use it like this:

```js
import {Chart} from "chart";

let c = new Chart(1);
```

Note: this assumes that the **Chart** function will be available in the global context.

You don't have to declare your own .d.ts files for everything, there are also tools that might help you. Like [typings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings) or [tsd](http://definitelytyped.org/tsd/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have tried that, and the link you post is the same i've posted. The problem is that SystemJS search for a chart.js that does not exist and the app broke...

Comment: It would help if you could point us to the chart.js library. :)

Comment: Yes, but the matter is not which chart. Sorry if i don't explain better. With those assumption:
- defined somelibrary.d.ts
- imported that module.
- compilation will success
On runtime SystemJS try to fetch the library (i think due to compilation option). I try to update the question explaining better

Answer (score 0):

You are using the export of chart.js in a value position, e.g. not only for its type so TypeScript emits it as a dependency when it transpiles your module. The problem is that chart.js is not available to the loader. 
I suggest you declare it in your SystemJS config either in map or packages, 
e.g. `'path': 'path/to/chart.js'`, and remove the script tag.

If you need to use a script tag for some reason, change your type declaration file to

```
export interface Chart {
  new (ctx: any);
  Doughnut(data: any, options: any): Function;
}
```

Note that you can also configure SystemJS to load chart.js via a cdn or whatever.

Personally, I would avoid the script tag and load it as a proper module. You may find this helpful:
http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-installation